# Display File Count and Subfolder size in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

Let's say I have Explorer open with the folder tree structure in the left-hand pane, and the subfolders and files in the right-hand pane.

Is there a way that I can see the number of files under the folder, and the total size of all data in the subfolder in the right-hand pane?

Comment: I would like to see this as well. You figured they would have built into Windows by now... If you are willing to spend for that feature take a look at http://www.zabkat.com/x2facts.htm

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a plugin but it supposedly shows directory sizes http://www.freecommander.com/fc_details_en.htm

Comment: It's not builtin, because all the current methods are not only inaccurate, but they are also IO intensive, considering it is a task users rarely use. Best left up to third party programs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use FolderSize on a server at work to administrate more effectively. It's essentially a Windows Explorer plugin that allows you to display folder-children, both files and folders along with their size.

http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/

Comment: +1 FolderSize..XP and Windows 2000 only

Comment: But what about file count of each subfolder?

Comment: Due to the age of this answer, there may be something better available now. I recommend you open a new question with that question.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible using the default Windows Explorer, you would need some sort of plugin that aggregates this information (or check them manually). You can, however, get this information from a Command Shell (albeit not in a pretty way) via "dir /S". Run "dir /?" for other options. For example:

```
C:\Users\Josh\Temp\apache-ant-1.8.1>dir /S
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is D819-69BC

 Directory of C:\Users\Josh\Temp\apache-ant-1.8.1

09/06/2010  06:07 PM    <DIR>          .
09/06/2010  06:07 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/06/2010  06:06 PM    <DIR>          bin
09/06/2010  06:07 PM    <DIR>          docs
09/06/2010  06:07 PM    <DIR>          etc
04/30/2010  06:03 PM             7,920 fetch.xml
04/30/2010  06:03 PM             4,566 get-m2.xml
04/30/2010  06:03 PM               128 INSTALL
04/30/2010  06:03 PM            77,892 KEYS
09/06/2010  06:08 PM    <DIR>          lib
04/30/2010  06:03 PM            15,561 LICENSE
04/30/2010  06:03 PM               224 NOTICE
04/30/2010  06:03 PM             4,216 README
04/30/2010  06:03 PM           197,028 WHATSNEW
               8 File(s)        307,535 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\Josh\Temp\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin

09/06/2010  06:06 PM    <DIR>          .
09/06/2010  06:06 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/30/2010  06:02 PM             9,997 ant
04/30/2010  06:02 PM             7,706 ant.bat
04/30/2010  06:02 PM             2,857 ant.cmd
04/30/2010  06:02 PM             3,410 antenv.cmd
04/30/2010  06:02 PM               861 antRun
04/30/2010  06:02 PM             1,536 antRun.bat
04/30/2010  06:02 PM             2,199 antRun.pl
04/30/2010  06:02 PM             3,219 complete-ant-cmd.pl
04/30/2010  06:02 PM             4,315 envset.cmd
04/30/2010  06:02 PM             1,116 lcp.bat
04/30/2010  06:02 PM             4,422 runant.pl
04/30/2010  06:02 PM             3,396 runant.py
04/30/2010  06:02 PM             1,817 runrc.cmd
              13 File(s)         46,851 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\Josh\Temp\apache-ant-1.8.1\docs
...
```

Comment: There is DIRUSE.EXE as well, which does the job a lot better.  I think I must have got it from the Windows Server 200 or 2003 Resource Kit.

Comment: DIRUSE is not available for versions of Windows after Server 2003.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who may stumble on this question and need an answer - [DU from sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651.aspx)

Similar in usage to the unix utility.

Comment: I love DU but the OP wanted something that would work in his Explorer display (or I presume an Explorer-like display). DU produces text only.

Comment: This is exactly the best convenient tool for list no. of filer per subfolder under a folder with certain depth on Windows.

Comment: However, it doesn't support list list file in differnt size unit. It only supports kb.

Comment: It doesn't support list no. of files and size of each subfolder in the mean time. Kinda pitty.

Answer (score 2):

[WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) is defnitely the best and fastest choice.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is looking for something there is a free tool to use http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/

Answer (score 1):

This is actually really easy.

Right-click the folder, select "Properties" and you will see the information you want on the first tab "General" following "Contains."

This is really easy to do!