# How to see if a folder contains a file at a glance?

Tags: windows

I have a directory in Windows containing many folders. I have to place one file in each folder, so I'd like to see at a glance if each folder contains a file. I tried enabling 'File Count' (see below) but nothing shows up at all under this column. How can I easily see if each folder contains a file?
[image: File count not visible.]

Comment: Related: [Display File Count and Subfolder size in Windows Explorer](http://superuser.com/questions/191585/display-file-count-and-subfolder-size-in-windows-explorer)

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version?

Comment: Write a script? (if you can)

Answer (score 6):

Try some different views. Some of them show different icons for empty and non-empty folders, e.g. tile:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately those are not always reliable. I have a few folders that have many files/folders in them that show as a blank folder. It may work for him where the folders all have just 1 or 0 files, but it doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: This, is a good compromise. I'd really like it to display properly in the 'Details' view though.

Comment: Yea, I was hoping to find a column to show the size of the contents, but this just doesn't seem to be natively supported.

Comment: If you select the folder in the LEFT pane, the count should appear at the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: This only seems to work intermittently. Sometimes it won't 'display' a file in the folder even if it contains one

Comment: @blarg The only other option I can think of is trying a third-party file explorer. Alternatively, drop to the command-line and just use a script as Shiki suggested in his comment.